# TypeError: this.formGroup.get(...).push is not a function Angular

Tags: angular, input, angular8

Суть проблемы, у меня есть форма создание рецептов есть кнопка Add Ingredients при котором должно появляться дополнительное поле ингредиента и так каждый раз при нажатие как на рисунку ниже то есть у меня есть форма редактирование и там всё работает отлично но на компоненте создания нового , выдает ошибку `TypeError: this.formGroup.get(...).push is not a function`
не понимаю в чём дело очень надеюсь на вашу помощь
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой **Component**

```
export class RecipeCreateComponent implements OnInit {
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  faSave = faSave;
  faDelete = faTrashAlt;
  recipe: Recipe;

  constructor(
    private recipeService: RecipeService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.formGroup.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    const recipe: Recipe = {
      name: this.formGroup.value.name,
      description: this.formGroup.value.description,
      imagePath: this.formGroup.value.imagePath,
      timeOfCock: this.formGroup.value.timeOfCock,
      ingredients: this.formGroup.value.ingredients,
      steps: this.formGroup.value.steps,
      date: new Date()
    };

    this.recipeService.createRecipe(recipe)
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.formGroup.reset();
      });
  }

  initForm() {
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      description: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      imagePath: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      timeOfCock: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      ingredients: new FormControl(new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl(Validators.required),
        amount: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
      })),
      steps: new FormControl(new FormGroup({
        text: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
      }))
    });

  }

  onCancel() {
    this.router.navigate(['/recipes'], {relativeTo: this.route});
  }


  get controlsIngredients() {
    return (this.formGroup.get('ingredients') as FormArray).controls;
  }

  get controlsSteps() {
    return (this.formGroup.get('steps') as FormArray).controls;
  }

  onAddIngredient(): void {
    (this.formGroup.get('ingredients') as FormArray).push(
      new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        amount: new FormControl(null,
          [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.pattern(/^[1-9]+[0-9]*$/)
          ]
        )
      })
    );

  }

  onAddSteps() {
    (this.formGroup.get('steps') as FormArray).push(
      new FormGroup({
        text: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
      })
    );
  }

  onDeleteIngredient(id: number) {
    (this.formGroup.get('ingredients') as FormArray).removeAt(id);
  }

  onDeleteStep(id: number) {
    (this.formGroup.get('steps') as FormArray).removeAt(id);
  }
```

И мой **Template** не весь конечно только проблемное место

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 form-group" formArrayName="ingredients">
    <label class="text-uppercase">Ingredients</label>
    <div
      class="row mb-2"
      *ngFor="let ingredientCtrl of controlsIngredients; let i = index"
      [formGroupName]="i"
    >
      <!--              количество ингредиентов-->
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <input
          type="number"
          class="form-control"
          formControlName="amount"
          placeholder="Amount">
      </div>
      <!--             название ингредиентов-->
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          formControlName="name"
          placeholder="Name">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <button
          class="btn btn-danger"
          (click)="onDeleteIngredient(i)">
          <fa-icon [icon]="faDelete"></fa-icon>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="onAddIngredient()">Add Ingredients</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Ошибка**

[image]

Comment: шаблон что я cкинул только часть формы, у меня есть форма отправки рецепта а то что я скинул только по сути елемент добавления ингредиентов
**Submit**
`<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="formGroup">`

Comment: А вы уверенны, что this.formGroup.get(...) возвращает массив?

Comment: у меня есть компонент редактирования с точно таким же методом и там я получаю массив ингредиентов всё работает и етот метод работает отлично но при создании нового рецепта ето уже другой компонент ничего не работает

Comment: ты не понял сути вопроса

Comment: ты можешь ответ на свой вопрос дать в виде **ответа** к своему же вопросу и позже пометить его галочкой, чтоб он не висел как _нерешенный_

Comment: ок через 2 дня отмечу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

спасибо очень признателен все заработало ниже решения вопроса как сделал, переделал метод `initForm()`

```
initForm() {
    const recipeIngredients = new FormArray([]);
    const recipeSteps = new FormArray([]);
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      description: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      imagePath: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      timeOfCock: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      ingredients: recipeIngredients,
      steps: recipeSteps
    });

  }
```